# unique permalink for multiple category

Tags: .htaccess, url, wordpress

How to make unique permalinks even if the post included in multiple category ?

```
Custom Structure /%category%/%postname%
```

multiple permalinks for same article effecting the facebook like count

presently seems to be like this, how can make this only for one ? 
[image]

Comment: There is no pattern! The category is variable and so is the post, the only constant is the domain name. Unless you want to have a rewriting rule for every post, I don't think there is an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use help from "SEO plugins", just search on the wordpress plugins.

recently I'm using Yoast SEO plugin, http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-seo/

to customize the permalink with categories.